# Save html page with images and css in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

How can I save html page with css and images, then to local show UIWebView? please help

Comment: I use this tutorial, but i need full html page with css files and images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ASIHTTPRequest project](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) has a class called `ASIWebPageRequest` which is designed to do exactly what you want. If you're okay with adding an additional dependency to your project then I think it's a good solution for you: [ASIWebPageRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest).

There are loads of code examples in the above link provided.

Comment: Thank you, I will explore this big project